# does select statement come under the category of Transact-SQL (T-SQL) is Microsoft's and Sybase's proprietary extension to SQL

Tags: sql

does select statement come under the category of Transact-SQL (T-SQL) is Microsoft's and Sybase's proprietary extension to SQL.

Comment: I'm guessing this is asked in light of this question: http://serverfault.com/questions/201524/what-is-the-difference-between-sql-and-ansi-sql

Answer (score 1):

MS T-SQL Select: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx

```
SELECT [ ALL | DISTINCT ] 
    [TOP ( expression ) [PERCENT] [ WITH TIES ] ] 

    < select_list > 
    [ INTO new_table ] 
    [ FROM { <table_source> } [ ,...n ] ] 
    [ WHERE <search_condition> ] 
    [ <GROUP BY> ] 
    [ HAVING < search_condition > ]
```

ANSI SQL Select:  http://www.rawos.com/odbc/sqlguide/index.html

```
SELECT [DISTINCT|ALL] *|{attr_name[ AS new_attr_name]} FROM {table_or_view[ alias]}
    [ WHERE where_criteria] 
    [ GROUP BY {attributes}[ HAVING condition]]
    [ ORDER BY {attrname|attrorder [ASC|DESC]}]
    [ INTERSECT|UNION[ ALL] SELECT_statement]
```

Yes, T-SQL Select is an extended (and therefore likely proprietary) version of ANSI Select.