# what is the difference between SQL and ANSI SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql

what is the difference between SQL  and ANSI SQL?

Answer (score 7):

"ANSI SQL" is a [series of standards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Standardization) for modeling and manipulating data. "SQL" is whatever bits of ANSI SQL a SQL engine vendor chooses to implement, plus whatever else they want to add.